Artin-Wedderburn application - finding simple modules
I'm trying to solve the following:

Let $R$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $R:=M_2(\mathbb{R})\times M_3(\mathbb{H})\times\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$. Determine how many simple (left) $R$-modules there are up to isomorphism and their dimensions over $\mathbb{R}$. Here $\mathbb{H}$ is the Hamilton quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, which has dimension 4.

My attempt:
Based on the Artin-Wedderburn theorem, I think we can say there are 4 simple modules up to isomorphism. I'm confused on how to deterimine their dimensions. If we were working over $\mathbb{C}$ we could just take the $n_i$ (the matrix dimensions) to be the dimensions of the modules over $\mathbb{C}$. But in this case we're working over $\mathbb{R}$. My naive thought is to conclude that the dimensions should be $2\cdot n_i$ because $\mathbb{C}$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ but this seems too easy.

Think of the matrix ring as a module over itself. Then $M_n(k)$ breaks up as $n$ copies of the natural module, the $n$-dimensional simple module over $k$. Thus $M_3(\mathbb{H})$, for example, breaks up as three copies of a $3$-dimensional module/vector space over $\mathbb{H}$. Now you just need the dimension of a $3$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{H}$, viewed as a module over $\mathbb{R}$, so $12$.
The same works for the other factors.
So you are right for $\mathbb{C}$, and you have to use $4$ for $\mathbb{H}$.
